# Gradle Kotlin DSL cannot generate Mapper implementation class using Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea, mapstruct, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to generate mapstruct implementation class and it is not getting generated.
I am using:

1. Springboot: 2.7.5
2. Kotlin: 1.7.21
3. Gradle: 7.5.1
4. Intellij 2022.2.3 (Ultimate)
5. Java 17

Following are my implementation classes:

1. **build.gradle.kts**

   ```
   import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

   plugins {
        id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.5"
        id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"

        val kotlinVersion = "1.7.21"
        kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
        kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
        kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion
   }

   java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

   buildscript {
      dependencies {
          classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:1.4.21")
          classpath("net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.21")
      }
   }

   apply(plugin = "kotlin-jpa")
   apply(plugin = "net.ltgt.apt-idea")


   dependencies {
         val querydslVersion = "5.0.0"

         implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
         api("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$querydslVersion")
         kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:$querydslVersion") 

         val mapstructVersion = "1.5.3.Final"

      implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$mapstructVersion")
         kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$mapstructVersion")
   }

   kapt {

    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor")
     //      arguments {
     // Set Mapstruct Configuration options here
     //        arg("mapstruct.defaultComponentModel", "spring")
     //    } 
   }

   tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
       kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
       }
   }

   tasks.withType<Test> {
         useJUnitPlatform()
   }
   ```
2. **DomainModelMapper.kt**

   ```
   @Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING, 
           unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
   interface DomainModelMapper {

        @Mappings(
             Mapping(source = "firstName", target = "first_name"),
             Mapping(source = "lastName", target = "last_name"),
        )
        fun accountCreateToAccount(accountCreate:AccountCreateRequest):Account
    }
   ```

**Exception**

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'com.*****.backend.config.DomainModelMapper' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: {}
```

I also enabled Annotation Processing in IntelliJ. Below is the screenshot:
[image: Intellij annotation processsor]

I do not have Lombok in my project. I have tried the [official doc](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/#gradle), [mapstruct spring extension plugin](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/spring-extensions/reference/html/#_gradle), various SO answers, and blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me, I've executed the code as follows:

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"

    val kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"

    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:1.4.21")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "kotlin-jpa")

dependencies {
    val mapstructVersion = "1.5.3.Final"

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")


    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:$mapstructVersion")
    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:$mapstructVersion")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**DomainModelMapper.kt**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING,
    unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
interface DomainModelMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "firstName", target = "first_name")
    @Mapping(source = "lastName", target = "last_name")
    fun accountCreateToAccount(accountCreate: AccountCreateRequest): Account
}
```

And your data classes:

```
data class Account(
    val first_name: String,
    val last_name: String
)

data class AccountCreateRequest(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String
)
```

You can see that the output is as follow:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)

2022-11-19 16:46:54.420  INFO 45217 --- [           main] com.yonatankarp.AppKt                    : Starting AppKt using Java 11.0.15 on XYZ with PID 45217 (/Users/yonatankarp/IdeaProjects/sandbox/build/classes/kotlin/main started by yonatankarp in /Users/yonatankarp/IdeaProjects/sandbox)
2022-11-19 16:46:54.421  INFO 45217 --- [           main] com.yonatankarp.AppKt                    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-11-19 16:46:54.924  INFO 45217 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-11-19 16:46:54.929  INFO 45217 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-19 16:46:54.929  INFO 45217 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68]
2022-11-19 16:46:54.974  INFO 45217 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-11-19 16:46:54.974  INFO 45217 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 520 ms
2022-11-19 16:46:55.117  INFO 45217 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-11-19 16:46:55.123  INFO 45217 --- [           main] com.yonatankarp.AppKt                    : Started AppKt in 0.859 seconds (JVM running for 1.032)
```

Please note that according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082576/type-javacompile-property-options-compilerargumentproviders-apt0-name-is-mi) answer `net.ltgt.apt-idea` is no longer needed after Gradle 7.2 and actually failed my build...

Comment: which version of kotlin?

Comment: As you can see in the `build.gradle.kts` above I'm using the same version -`1.6.0` :)

Comment: the only changes I did was removing the plugins and adding the `repositories` section - I added the data classes for you to ensure that they're looking the same as you'd expect them to look like

Comment: Hi, my bad, I overlooked it. Thank you. I tried with your configs and unfortunately, the issue still persists. I have then updated kotlin to 1.7.21 and my intellij to 2022.2.3. To add I also have mongo annotation processor. That seems to work. I am updating the post now. Please have a look.

Comment: Could you maybe create a minimal github repo that reproduces the issue that I can clone and run locally? I think that it would become easier to understand the root cause

Comment: Good idea, I think that the mapper functions are wrong in terms of source and destination classes. I will check it out, if that does not work, I will create a minimal repo. Thanks for your help and prompt response. :)

Comment: Sure thing, let me know at the end so I can update my answer accordingly as the response for this question :)

Comment: My apologies for responding late. I have now created a minimal application, but the issue seems to still persist. Following is the repo link: https://github.com/shibasish/mapstruct-springbooot-demo

Comment: Have you tried this one BTW? https://3lexw.medium.com/how-to-use-mapstruct-in-kotlin-spring-with-injection-spring-services-and-repositories-5c3f468ee261